# I accidentally used CMD+drag to remove my fast switching icon. How can I restore it?

Tags: macos

In the top right hand corner, near where the Notifications sit used to be the name of the account I was using on this computer. I CMD+clicked it as you can use this to re-arrange the bar. I dragged it off the bar by mistake and it's disappeared. How can I restore this please?

Answer (score 4):

- Open System Preferences / Users & Groups
- click lock to make changes
- click Login Options
- Check "Show fast user switching menu as ..." (in Mountain Lion)

Account name should now appear on the menubar again.

Answer (score 0):

Open a Finder window, click `Go -> Go to Folder` and go to the following folder:

```
/System/Library/CoreServices/Menu Extras
```

There you should see the file `User.menu`, double click it and if all is correct you should have your account name back in the menu bar.